# Cypress fixtures - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: cypress, fixtures

I'm trying to use fixtures to hold data for different tests, specifically user credentials. This is an example of the code. When it gets to the second test I'm getting `'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')'`.

Any ideas why and how I can get around that? Is that wrong?

```js
before(function () {
    cy.fixture('credentials').then(function (data) {
        this.data = data;
    })
})

    it('Login correct', () => {
        cy.visit('/')
        loginPage.signIn(this.data.admin.username,this.data.admin.password)
        cy.wait(5000)
        // assertion
        cy.contains('Dashboard').should('be.visible')
    })
```

And here is my `credentials.json` file:

```js
{
  "admin": {
    "username": "*****",
    "password": "*****"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using closure variables to assign fixture data.

```js
describe('Some Test', () => {
  let data; //closure variable
  before(() => {
    cy.fixture('credentials').then((fData) => {
        data = fData;
    });
  });

    it('Login correct', () => {
        cy.visit('/')
        loginPage.signIn(data.admin.username, data.admin.password) //usage of closure variable to get the values from the fixtures
        cy.wait(5000)
        // assertion
        cy.contains('Dashboard').should('be.visible')
    });
});
```

[Gleb Bahmutov also recommends using closure variables.](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/import-cypress-fixtures/)

> I strongly recommend using closure variables instead of this properties. The closure variables are clearly visible and do not depend on `function` vs `() => {}` syntax.

Comment: Thank you agoff for your answer, it's working! But if you can the `=>` in the before() function, it would be perfect!

Comment: Ah my bad, completely spaced on that, was more focused on removing the `function` part.

Answer (score 6):

As per the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#this-context):

> If you store and access the fixture data using this test context
> object, make sure to use function () { ... } callbacks. Otherwise, the
> test engine will NOT have this pointing at the test context.

So, your `it` block should also use function:

```js
before(function () {
  cy.fixture('credentials').then(function (data) {
    this.data = data
  })
})

it('Login correct', function () {
  cy.visit('/')
  loginPage.signIn(this.data.admin.username, this.data.admin.password)
  cy.wait(5000)
  // assertion
  cy.contains('Dashboard').should('be.visible')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answes are correct. One more way to do the above operation is use cypress.json instead  other json files.

In your cypress.json u can add the credentials :

```
{
  "Env": {
    "username": "*****",
    "password": "*****"
  }
}
```

and refere json directy in your **it** fucntion.

```
it('Login correct', function () {
  cy.visit('/')
  loginPage.signIn(Cypress.env('username'), Cypress.env('password'))
  cy.wait(5000)
  // assertion
  cy.contains('Dashboard').should('be.visible')
})
```

Comment: I don't think your answer is quite right. If set in the `cypress.json`, they'll need to be under the `env` object. I think you're implying using a `cypress.env.json` file. Either way, the values in `Cypress.env()` will need to be prepended with `admin.` -> `Cypress.env('admin.username')`. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Setting

Comment: @agoff yes you are right. I missed that part Sorry. In Cypress json, I need to bind username and password inside env. I wil correct my answer thanks 

Comment: @agoff - Thanks for the link and explanation. But why do you need the `admin.` prefix?

Comment: @Matt I believe at the time I posted that comment, Umesh's answer had the `username` and `password` fields underneath an `admin` object (similar to OP's `credentials.json` file.) As Umesh's answer is currently, there is no need for `admin.` prefix.