# Cannot read values from file in fixture folder, getting error as "TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')"

Tags: javascript, json, cypress, fixtures

I'm trying to use fixtures to hold data for different tests, specifically user credentials. This is an example of the code.  I'm getting 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')'. I tried to google search , I found [Cypress fixtures - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70929268/cypress-fixtures-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-data)

I used closure variable  technique as reccomended in that post , yet I got reference error of unable to reference data.Please help me.I know cypress.config can be used but I want to keep that for global configs

Json(credentials.json):

```
{
    "username":"*****",
    "password":"*****"
}
```

Code:

```
import { LoginPage } from "./pageobject/login_page"
describe('Test Scenario', () => {
    before(function () {
        cy
            .fixture('credentials').then(function (data) {
                this.data = data
            })
    })
    it('Simple login', () => {
       
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('url'))
        var loginpage = new LoginPage()
        loginpage.EnterUsername(this.data.username)
        loginpage.clickonSubmit()
        loginpage.EnterPassword(this.data.password)
        loginpage.clickonSubmit()
         Cypress
            .on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
                return false;
            });
        cy.
            wait(10000)
        cy.
            get('span[id="user"]').should('have.text', this.data.username , 'User Login Unsuccessfully')



    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to use fixtures to hold data for different tests, This is an example of the code. where I'm getting 'Cannot read properties of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72305668/im-trying-to-use-fixtures-to-hold-data-for-different-tests-this-is-an-example) - the correct answer is @agoff's, almost precisely what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things need adjusting

- use `function () {}` syntax in the `it()` block
- use `beforeEach()` and alias to load the fixture, because data on `this` can be cleared (especially after login)
- move `uncaught:exception` catcher to the top of the block
- don't `cy.wait()`, instead add timeout to next command
- `.should()` only has two parameters in this case, so use `.and()` to test the 2nd text

```js
import { LoginPage } from './pageobject/login_page';

describe('Test Scenario', () => {

    beforeEach(function () {
        cy.fixture('credentials').as('data')
    })

    it('Simple login', function() {

        Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
            return false;
        });

        cy.visit(Cypress.env('url'));
        var loginpage = new LoginPage();
        loginpage.EnterUsername(this.data.username);
        loginpage.clickonSubmit();
        loginpage.EnterPassword(this.data.password);
        loginpage.clickonSubmit();

        cy.get('span[id="user"]', {timout:10_000})
          .should('have.text', this.data.username)
          .and('have.text', 'User Login Unsuccessfully')
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks man. I am new to cypress , would you help tell me the coding standards in cypress

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you are using an arrow function instead of a regular function, you cannot access the `this` object with an arrow function.

[Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#this-context)

> If you store and access the fixture data using this test context
> object, make sure to use function () { ... } callbacks. Otherwise the
> test engine will NOT have this pointing at the test context.

change it to this:

```
it('Simple login', function() {
       

   ...

    });
```